# how to force proguard to merely obfuscate classes in the given jar file?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

Actually, I'm looking for the solution to obfuscate a whole apk file using proguard. The most common approach is to unzip the apk first. Then convert the decompressed classes.dex to the jar format. Next run command `proguard @proguard.cfg` to obfuscate the jar file. Finally after obfuscating compress the content back to form the whole apk.

Following is the content of `proguard.cfg`,

```
-injars in.jar
-outjars out.jar
-verbose
```

However, there are always errors of unresolved references when running `proguard @proguard.cfg`. I know it is caused by necessary libs missing. However, it is really trivial to config the libs for each one when having more than 1000 apks. So is there any workaround to obfuscate apks in batch manner via proguard? In other words, force proguard to ignore classes from outer libs and merely obfuscate the classes in the given jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution. Just add one option which will suppress all the unresolved reference warnings. That is `-dontwarn` which is used to control the warnings. If it is set to `-dontwarn **`, the obfuscation process will ignore all the warnings. For other useful options, please see https://github.com/facebookarchive/proguard/blob/master/examples/android.pro